# No se pudo encontrar un archivo de declaración para el módulo 'rn-checkbox-list'

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox, javascript-import

Instalé el paquete rn-checkbox-list en mi proyecto, pero cuando hago el **import CheckboxList from 'rn-checkbox-list';** el VSCode me muestra lo siguiente:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'rn-checkbox-list'. 'd:/Desarrollos/Reactnative/ensayosgenerales/node_modules/rn-checkbox-list/src/checkList.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/rn-checkbox-list` if it exists or **add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'rn-checkbox-list';** ts(7016)
module "d:/Desarrollos/Reactnative/ensayosgenerales/node_modules/rn-checkbox-list/src/checkList"

Intenté sin éxito lo primero que propone, pero no comprendo como implementar la segunda opción (la marcada en negrita). Me he guiado de otras soluciones encontradas en la web, como [esta](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/could+not+find+a+declaration+file+for+module+%27react-native-navigation%27) por ejemplo, pero no logro que desaparezca la adventencia.

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Es un error de TypeScript. Este se configura en **tsconfig** para la validación del código. Si quieres simplemente omitir el error configura `noImplicitAny: false`. De lo contrario, lo siguiente:

Crea un archivo en la raíz del proyecto llamado **global.d.ts** y agrega ahí el `declare module 'rn-checkbox-list`.

Comment: No logro que funcione @Esteban. Estoy utilizando React Native Cli y VSCode (desconozco si tiene algo que ver), pero sigue apareciendo la leyenda.

Comment: ¿Podrías pegar imágenes de tu código formato o algo que ayude a entender un poco más como tienes configurado el proyecto?. Archivos de configuración que tienes de TS, lo que hiciste de lo que sugerí y cualquier otra cosa que veas que pueda ayudar a revisar mejor tu código.

Comment: Esteban, creo que sería algo extenso. Tal vez haya un "modo base" para implementar en proyectos nuevos.  No encuentro el archivo _tsconfig_ buscando dentro del proyecto abierto en VSCode. Estoy trabajando con JavaScript. 
Pude crear el archivo como me sugeriste, pero nada mas. 
Entiendo que debe ser complicado interpretarme, tal vez tengas alguna lectura o link que puedas recomendarme.

Comment: Intenta con `npm i --save-dev @types/rn-checkbox-list`. Lo probé en reactJs con TS. Espero que sirva también con RN

Comment: Lo intenté Esteban, pero no anduvo. Me sale lo siguiente:

`npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2frn-checkbox-list - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/rn-checkbox-list@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.`

Comment: Tienes un archivo tsconfig.ts cierto? Si es así, incluye lo siguiente
```"include": [
    "src",
    "rn-checkbox-list"
  ]```

Comment: No tengo @Esteban ese archivo en mi proyecto.

Comment: Lo último: Agregar en la raíz `typing/index.d.ts`y adentro agrega `declare module 'rn-checkbox-list`;

Comment: Lamentablemente tampoco anduvo, incluso lo hice con otro componente con el que tenía el mismo inconveniente _declare module 'react-native-select-multiple';_ y no logré solucionarlo. Si encuentro el modo lo publicaré. Seguiré investigando...